# Trouble mapping <control-pipe> in new keybinds

Tags: key-bindings, split

I've recently decided to improve my multiple-pane Vim workflow, so I'm adding some new mappings to avoid the awkward `<C-W>` command. 
Here's what I have currently:

```
" split-pane navigation remaps                                                   
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j                                                            
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k                                                            
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h                                                            
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l                                                            
nnoremap <c-|> :vsplit<cr>                                                     
nnoremap <c-_> :split<cr>                                                        
set splitbelow                                                                   
set splitright
```

Right now, everything works except the `<c-|>` vertical split. It is my understanding that the syntax would normally be `<c-|>`, but since `|` is a special character, it must be escaped. Here's what I found through `:help map_bar`

```
Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next          
command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.       
There are three methods:                                                         
   use       works when                    example      ~                        
   <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M             
   \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M                
   ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi         :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M               

(here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you     
cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).
```

Unfortunately, I've tried the following and none of them seem to work:

```
nnoremap <c-|> :vsplit<cr>    
nnoremap <c-\|> :vsplit<cr>    
nnoremap <c-<bar>> :vsplit<cr>    
nnoremap <c-^V|> :vsplit<cr>
```

And yes, I got `^V` by holding Control and double-tapping V, not by typing Caret V. Thanks, any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using? Oh my macbook, the \ key requires a shift press and I don't think CTRL+SHIFT mappings are possible. Also, have you tried escaping `\<bar>`?

Comment: I'm using a standard US keyboard layout on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I just tried `\<bar>`, that didn't work either.

Comment: The correct syntax would've been `<c-bar>`.  Unfortunately, `<bar>` usually doesn't work with control key [Vim: vim_faq.txt](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5)

Comment: Thanks for a definitive answer! Too bad it's a no.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<c-\>`, which despite the backslash doesn't need to be escaped in maps.

Alternatively, `<c-bslash>` is the same, useful in cases such as strings where the backslash has meaning.